# How can I find the current draw of an SN74HC595 when OE is disabled?

Tags: current

I am trying to daisy chain 4 SN74HC595's together in an "always on" battery powered system.  When the system is "off" I am disabling a few components via their **EN** pin to lower current into the 10's of uA. 
I can't seem to determine how much current these SN74HC595 chips will draw when I set the !OE pin to disable the output.

Any help would be wonderfully appreciated!  I could always add a load switch for this, but I'd rather do it elegantly rather than add more components.

Specifically, this chip: [SN74HC595BRWNR](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/SN74HC595BRWNR/296-44070-1-ND/5985446).
Here's a snapshot of (I think?) the pertinent information from its datasheet.
[image]
I can't tell from this if the current would be up to 1000 nA (maka 1uA) by disabling via !OE, or if I just need to be sure to set all logic inputs to 0 to obtain that level of minimal current draw.

Anyway, again any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

Edit: actually after reading through my post again, is it fair to assume that **Icc** is the current draw? and based on its *Test Conditions*, if Io (Iout?) is 0, then the device should only draw 8uA at normal temperatures.  and I can be sure Iout is 0 by disabling the device with !OE?..

I think?

Comment: Remember that Icc is the static current, if the clock is active you need to use the power dissipation capacitance to calculate the power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum is 8uA at room temperature, 80uA at up to 85°C. But those are very loose specifications. The *typical* Icc is about 27nA with a 5V supply at 25°C. As a rule of thumb, it will approximately double for every 10°C above room temperature.

[image]

That's assuming all the inputs are near the rails and static. If inputs are not near the rails the current can go up considerably due to conduction of the input transistors, and similarly if they are switching. Cpd is specified as 400pF (typical) and there is an explanation of how to use that [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa035b/scaa035b.pdf?ts=1588363537754).

If the input strays too far from the rails, then shoot-through current can greatly increase the tiny leakage current broadly similar to this effect:

(from [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scba004d/scba004d.pdf) document):

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!  This is awesome and great information.   You rock!

Answer (score 1):

The input current or I_i won't change, it will remain at 1000nA.

The output current Ioz will go to 5uA Max when the Output is disabled.

The output enable won't change the power consumption of the part much (the power consumed by quiescent current and inputs), but it will change the power delivered to the loads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is shown on the datasheet as Icc, it is either 8uA, 160uA, or 80uA, depending on your temperature range.